# Connect C++ application to a website server and retrieve files based on a password

Tags: c++, ftp, server

Let's say I have:

> 1) A C++ application
>
> 2) A website server

First of all, I will give the application to some users and I want these users to have access to some files of my website server (this of course will happen internally, for example the user will press a button and the application will load some images from the server).

However, I need each user to have access to different files. Meaning, I want to be able to give a password to a user called `USER_A` and this specific user using the password I gave him, he will press a button, enter the password and load some images from a folder called `DIR_A`, same way a user called `USER_B` with another password will have access to images in a folder called `DIR_B`, etc. Something like how website members work when they sign in to a website.

I know my question is a bit ambiguous but:

> 1) Is that even possible
>
> 2) If yes, where to start from? What would I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- setup your webserver to return different files based on the http request
- use the password to form your url
- The application will use a GET request to the following urls:

```
https://example.com/password-a
https://example.com/password-b
```

- The server will return the appropriate files.
- use libcurl (easy curl) for http implementation
- for more security, send hashes instead of password, use https, require authentication, etc. etc.